# Circular array (Queue) Iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, queue

I have an iterator class for a queue (implemented as a circular array). I attach the code below. The problem is with the ++ operator. Once it reaches the end of the array, it circles back to its beginning, so the iterator points to the 1st element. It works fine but I have no way of implementing then end() iterator using this method. The functions that return the begin() and end() iterators inside the queue class can be seen at the bottom. The end() iterator should point to the rear of the queue, but when the array is full and rear equals the size of the array is does not work, the ++ operator will circle back instead of allowing it to the return the true end(), which is the element pointed by the rear. Any suggestions regarding this issue?

```
class IteratorForwQueue : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, P*> {
    public:
        typedef IteratorForwQueue iter;
        IteratorForwQueue(P* e, Queue* q) : elem(e), _queue(q) {}
        IteratorForwQueue(const IteratorForwQueue& it, Queue* q) :
            elem(it.elem), _queue(q) {}

        iter& operator++() {
            if(elem >= (_queue->_elems + (_queue->_size - 1)) &&
                            _queue->_rear != _queue->_size)
                elem = &(_queue->_elems[0]); // circle back passed the array
            else
                ++elem;
            return *this;
        }

        P& operator*() { return *elem;}
        P* operator->() { return elem; }
        bool operator==(const iter& it) { return elem == it.elem; }
        bool operator==(const P& e) { return e == *elem; }
        bool operator!=(const iter& it) { return elem != it.elem; }
        bool operator!=(const P& e) { return e != *elem; }
    private:
        P* elem;
        Queue<P>* _queue;
    }; // end of iterator class
// ....
IteratorForwQueue begin() { return IteratorForwQueue(_elems + _front, this); }
IteratorForwQueue end() { return IteratorForwQueue(_elems + _rear, this); }
```

Comment: Can you afford to waste a slot and use it as a sentinel?

Comment: The front and the rear of the queue changes as you enqueue and dequeue. I can’t have a sentinel if it changes

Comment: So here is the thing, if you had a queue implemented as a circular array, how would you implement the operator++ of its iterator?

Answer (score 0):

How about this, based on the idea that end does not have to be a "past-the-end" iterator, it can be anything:

```
class IteratorForwQueue : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, P*> {
public:
    typedef IteratorForwQueue iter;
    IteratorForwQueue(P* e, size_t sz, size_t rear) : elem(e), _base(e), _sz(sz), _rear(rear) {}
    IteratorForwQueue(const IteratorForwQueue& it, size_t sz) :
        elem(it.elem), _base(it.elem), _sz(sz) {}

    iter& operator++() {
       if(elem - _base == _rear) {
          elem = nullptr;
          _base = 0;
          _sz = 0;
          _rear = 0;
          return *this;
       } 
       if(elem >= _base + (_sz - 1))
            elem = _base; // circle back passed the array
        else
            ++elem;


        return *this;
    }

    P& operator*() { return *elem;}
    P* operator->() { return elem; }
    bool operator==(const iter& it) { return elem == it.elem; }
    bool operator==(const P& e) { return e == *elem; }
    bool operator!=(const iter& it) { return elem != it.elem; }
    bool operator!=(const P& e) { return e != *elem; }
private:
    P* elem;
    P* _base;  // can't access members of outer class
    size_t _sz; // can't access members of outer class
    size_t _rear;
}; // end of iterator class
// ....
IteratorForwQueue begin() { return IteratorForwQueue(_elems + _front, _size, _rear); }
IteratorForwQueue end() { return IteratorForwQueue(nullptr, 0, 0); }
const IteratorForwQueue cbegin() const { return     IteratorForwQueue(_elems + _front, _size); }
const IteratorForwQueue cend() const { return IteratorForwQueue(_elems + _rear, _size); }
```

BTW, it would be better to have a pointer back to the original datastructure, make the iterator a friend class and fetch `_base`, `_sz` and `_rear` on demand.

Comment: the code does not simplify, but i was thinking the same about passing the this pointer instead to point back to the original data structure. that and modifying the condition for the ++ operator did the trick, to circle back only if rear is not equal to size (see code). for documentation purposes copy the new code into your answer to mark it as the answer if u don't mind, thank you